# Does a partially traced density operator also become a Boltzmann density operator under Wick rotation to Euclidean space?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, density-operator, wick-rotation

I know that, under the Wick rotation $(i\Delta t/\hbar,p_0)\to(-\beta,-ip_{0,E})$, Feynman's path integral supposedly transforms into the traced-over Boltzmann partition function, $trace(e^{-\beta H})=trace(\rho_B)$. Furthermore, I realize that this suggests that, if one defines the total system's density operator by $\rho_{Total}=\psi^\dagger|0\rangle \langle0|\psi$, with $\psi$ the field annihilation operator, then the $e^{i[\int p \cdot dx-\int Hdt]/\hbar}=e^{i\int [p \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}-H]dt/\hbar}=e^{iS/\hbar}$ in the field operator becomes a central part of $\rho_{Total}$ and we can, in a manner of speaking, interpret the said Wick rotation as taking $\rho_{Total}\to \rho_{Total,E}$ (with E denoting the Euclidean version). (While the argument here is informal, a more exacting derivation leads to essentially the same conclusion.)

However, I'm wondering how general this transformation actually is: I'm currently working with the partial trace of $\rho_{Total}$, a pure density operator, and need to know if, following a partial trace, this Wick-rotation-induced transformation continues to work? That is, I'm sure it is valid for the total system's (pure) density operator, but does the transformation continue to be applicable if, say, the space or the time dependence is traced(/integrated) out (i.e., does $tr_t(\rho_{Total})\to e^{-\beta H'}=\rho'_B$ with a different Hamiltonian operator continue to be valid)?

Comment: it's unclear whether you are working with thermal or pure state density matrices

Comment: I am working initially with the partial trace of a pure density matrix. However, I want to know if it (the partial trace of the pure $\rho$) can be mapped to a thermal density matrix. If so, ideally, I would like to know the relation between the new (Euclidean/thermodynamic) Hamiltonian and the action in the original density matrix (loosely speaking).